# Ehcache.Cache.put does not works with a specific ColdFusion element (and takes about 4 seconds)

Tags: coldfusion, ehcache, coldfusion-9

I'm using ColdFusion 9 with Ehcache

Ehcache was working pretty well but since I re-installed my machine `Ehcache.Cache.put` refuse to work on a specific element but is working on tons of other elements.

`Cache.put` throws no exception and takes about 4 seconds to return.
The element I try to put in cache is a ColdFusion component and is only about 7ko. I don't use serialization.

The cache configuration is:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
         maxBytesLocalHeap="300m">
         
<sizeOfPolicy maxDepth="99999999" maxDepthExceededBehavior="continue"/>

<defaultCache 
    eternal="false" 
    timeToIdleSeconds="300" 
    timeToLiveSeconds="1200" 
    overflowToDisk="false"
    statistics="true">
```

I changed it to

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="900">

<defaultCache 
    eternal="false" 
    timeToIdleSeconds="300" 
    timeToLiveSeconds="1200" 
    overflowToDisk="false"
    statistics="true"
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="100">
```

And this works! Changing from a `maxBytesLocalHeap` to a `maxEntriesLocalHeap` config makes the difference! I think maybe the internal size calculation is not working. Using `maxEntriesLocalHeap` do not require size calculation that's why it works with the new configuration.

So why:

1. is `Cache.put` not working with `maxBytesLocalHeap` on only one specific
   element?
2. no exception?
3. `Cache.put` function takes 4 seconds?
4. this problem on a brand new machine re-installation?

If you have any clue, please let me know.
I really need to switch back to `maxBytesLocalHeap`.

PS:

- The application also uses JDK 1.6, MachII, Hibernate and ColdSpring

Comment: Even though ehcache runs with CF, this is not a CF question.  Your question is about why ehcache, a 3rd party tool, doesn't work so you're better off going to [http://ehcache.org/community](http://ehcache.org/community).  You can get to the forums from that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ehcache sizing of a ColdFusion element go too deep and process every Java underlying objects like ColdFusion frameworks objets, etc...

I fixed my issue by setting a filter. I use the system property `net.sf.ehcache.sizeof.filter` which points to text file location containing FQCN or fields for the sizing engine to ignore. Source: http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/6371.page

I set `net.sf.ehcache.sizeof.filter` by starting Java VM with `-D` argument like that:

```sh
-D net.sf.ehcache.sizeof.filter=/My/Path/To/File.config
```

My filter configuration file contains:

```
coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage
coldfusion.monitor.memory.MemoryTrackable
coldfusion.monitor.sql.QueryStat
coldfusion.monitor.memory.MemoryTrackerProxy
javax.servlet.ServletContext
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that under ColdFusion 11, if you are storing instances of Hibernate objects there are some additional exclusions to add. The final list is:

```
coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage
coldfusion.monitor.memory.MemoryTrackable
coldfusion.monitor.sql.QueryStat
coldfusion.monitor.memory.MemoryTrackerProxy
javax.servlet.ServletContext
org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl
org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl
```